# Using angular in a chrome extension gives me minErr is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

All I've done is to include Angular in my chrome extension and right of the bat it gives me a ´Uncaught ReferenceError:minErr is not defined´. I've tried multiple versions of Angular but the issue persists.

This is all I've done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Typography</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-latest/src/Angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>

</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/core.css">

<body ng-app="" ng-csp>
<h1>Typography</h1>
<div class="viewport">

    <form>
        <label for="baseline">Baseline</label>

        <div class="row clear"> 
            <input type="range" name="baselineRange" id="baselineRange" min="0" max="144" step="1"  />
            <input type="input" name="baseline" id="baseline"/>
        </div>

        <label for="offset">Baseline offset</label>
        <input type="text" name="offset" id="offset" />
        <button type="submit" id="send">Generate</button>

    </form>

    <p>Typography was created by <a href="//twitter.com/simpelism">Joel Sanden</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked through this one: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/issues/110

Comment: Yes but since I use the latest version of Angular the issue on github should be fixed already.

Comment: I wonder how about putting your all JS script files at the end of the html file.